# About 他 and 她 （regarding the song "break up 分手不分离" by z.tao)

Tags: pronouns

Im curious about a line from the song in using  他 and 她. The said line is

[因为我 想知道 **她**是不是比我好]

Isn't 她 supposed to refer to female?
The singer is a male so I'm kind of confused (since china is pretty Conservative) why he's using 她 to refer to his ex's new lover?

Ps. It is official lyric so I don't think it's a typo

Comment: 她 refer to his ex, 她(过的)是不是比我好, maybe

Comment: Maybe, the writer of the song is a female? However, a male singer sings it. Does this assumption make sense?

Comment: 作词：作曲：黄子韬. Is 黄子韬 a man or woman?

Comment: 看了mv，貌似这是写给他兄弟的，他兄弟喜欢一个女孩。 不过具体电视剧没看，搞不太清楚剧情。:(

Comment: @dan the singer(z.Tao) is also the one who wrote the lyric ^^ and i don't think there's a MV? i think the one that you watched is fanmade vid but it possible that maybe the lyric might refer to the drama's plot (hot blooded youth (热血少年)) I'll try to watch it tomorrow ^^

Comment: @TangHo Zitao is a man 

Comment: @车厘子 应该是电视或电影插曲或主题曲。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "心陪着你,  因为我想知道 她(他)是不是比我好"

He used '你'(you)  to refer his ex-girlfriend at the beginning of the sentence. It is wrong to use a different pronoun "她" to refer his ex-girlfriend in the same sentence later.

她 has to be a typo, It should be '他' not ''她 in this line

> "My heart is with you because I want to know if he is or isn't better than me"

(*Implying: If he is, I am happy for you, if he isn't, then come back*)

车厘子 wrote:

> Ps. It is official lyric so I don't think it's a typo

Official lyric can use the wrong word too.

'Made a typo' means the guy who typed the lyric mistakenly typed 她 instead of 他,

'Chosen the wrong word' means the guy who typed the lyric mistakenly thought 'XX' in 'XX 是不是比我好' was referring to the girlfriend instead of the girlfriend's new boyfriend